# ArcGIS unable to copy data into SqlLite

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sqlite

I'm testing the ability to use SQLLite with ArcGIS. I ran the python script Esri said, "sqlite_database_path = 'C:/sql_lite/CI.sqlite' and  arcpy.gp.CreateSQLiteDatabase(sqlite_database_path, "ST_GEOMETRY") it looks like it worked, ArcCatalog sees the database.

What I found is you have the options of using spatialLite, ST_Geometry, or the geopackage. I was thinking the ST_Geometry would let you use sqllite directly.

I saw comments where people copy/pasted data into sqllite but in ArcCatalog I didn't have the option to paste after I copied. I tried the ArcPy Copy_management, and import, both screamed "the application is not licensed to create or modify schema for this type of data"

I also found Esri said:
You cannot create a geodatabase in SQLite.
Feature services are not supported with SQLite.

So how are people putting GIS Featureclasses into sqllite from ArcMap?

Comment: What is your license level? I have an Advanced license and can copy/paste a featureclass into .sqlite db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @klewis alluded to, I think the issue you are having is related to your license level.  This technical article summarizes:  [Error: The application is not licensed to modify or create schema for this type of data](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000002603)
Based on that error, you likely have ArcGIS for Desktop Basic.  In order to create or modify a database schema, you need to have ArcGIS for Desktop Standard, or Advanced.

Your other option is to install an open source GIS package like [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/).  This would allow you to add/edit, in SQLite, and still view the data in ArcGIS.  I would suggest installing the [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) package if you want to go this route.

One last note about the data type of the **SQLite db**.  As you noted, there are 3 spatial types you could use, [Spatialite](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index), [ST_Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/databases/spatially-enable-sqlilte.htm), and [GeoPackage](http://www.geopackage.org/).  You were considering using `ST_Geometry`, which is ESRI's proprietary spatial type.  For the sake of data interoperability and portability, I would consider using the **GeoPackage**.  This is a fully [OGC](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) (Open Geospatial Consortium), standards-compliant data format.  It is supported not just by ArcGIS, but by all the major open-source packages as well.  This becomes more important given your current licensing limitations in ArcGIS.

Comment: I have the option of switching to Esri Advances, then paste showed up. I thought it couldn't be this because basic allowed me to create it, but... I did try st_geometry and Spatialite and Qgis saw that and allowed me to copy data to it. I also ran into permissions issues because the folder I created to put this in became read only, and the users did not have write permissions. I like your idea of a Geopackage.

Comment: Unless you are using a shared license through the license manager, I would keep your license level at Advanced simply as a matter of course.  There are lots of little things that you get locked out of at the lower levels, some that you may not even be aware of, others that are just frustrating as they are relatively common tasks.